# Facebook authentication using Passport in Node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

I am implementing a Facebook authentication using Passport in node.js. I can get the users profile from Facebook successfully. The problem is, the code should redirect the user to the successRedirect: /profile but instead it always goes to /fbFailure. No matter what I tried, it always goes to the url : somesite.com:6161/fbFailure#*=*

Passport middleware code:

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var models = require('../models');
passport.use('facebook', new FacebookStrategy(
{
    clientID: '1735552370024305', clientSecret: 'a004f1aee925b615022d7573984d5c26', callbackURL: "http://www.somesite.com:6161/facebookSuccess", profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'emails'],
},
function(access_token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('profile', profile);
models.Member.findOne({ '__id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
  if (err)
    return done(err); 
  if(user){
    return done(null, user);
  }
  done(null, user);
})
}
));
```

My Routes:

```
app.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook',  { scope : 'email' }));
app.get('/facebookSuccess', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/fbFailure'
    }));

app.get('/profile', function(req, res, next) {
 res.send('Successfully authenticated');
});

app.get('/fbFailure', function(req, res, next) {
 res.send('Failed to authenticate');
});
```

Console Output:

```
json: 
   { id: '10154130288931542',
     name: ‘Tom Verra’,
     picture: { data: [Object] },
     email: ‘tom.vera@mysite.com' } }
GET /facebookSuccess?code=AQBzdIfKPQ..............YU6TvYuf......
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your `passport.deserializeUser(callback)` and `passport.serializeUser(callback)` middlewares.

Comment: passport serializer, deserializer is common for both local and facebook strategies. This is what I have. passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting using `res.redirect('/profile');`, just the way it is done in the passport-facebook readme on GitHub (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#authenticate-requests):

```
app.get('/facebookSuccess',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/fbFailure' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/profile');
  });
```